# Removing IFRAME from Excel online?

Tags: python, ruby, excel, web-scraping, automated-tests

I use excel online a lot and am trying to automate a few tasks.  Before I can even begin, there is an iframe element that prevents anything being done.  Any way to get around this?  I'm using chrome and IE

Comment: I think we need more info... You are using "Excel online", and want to do what with CSS? Ruby or Python? Can you share some code that is causing you issues?? Are you running automated tests?

Comment: Ideally, yes.  But I can't really begin any project if there is a IFRAME there sadly